# Using a UserControl type vs a control's concrete type

Tags: wpf, xaml

Okay, I understand what a `UserControl` is and how they can be shared across multiple `Windows`/`Views` to share functionality, etc. Though, what is the benefit of using a `UserControl` type? It seems a lot cleaner if you were to use the root control instead of wrapping it inside a `UserControl`.

Example:

```
<UserControl>
   <Grid>
     //...
   <Grid/>
</UserControl>
```

vs.

```
<Grid>
  //...
</Grid>
```

Using the root control also has the benefit if reducing the `VisualTree`.

Answer (score 2):

`UserControl` has some properties it inherits from `ContentControl`, like [`ContentTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate(v=vs.110).aspx), [`ContentTemplateSelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx), some other stuff. If you don't need those, you can create a user control, change the outermost element to `Grid` and change its base class to `Grid` in the `.xaml.cs`, and it'll compile. At least with the trivial example I just tried, it works fine.

However, unless you've identified some concrete problem being created by `UserControl` in your application, I can't see any reason to go to the trouble. But go ahead, if you like doing things that way.

Comment: Right, I understand that UserControl does have some "special" properties, like the ones you have mentioned. I've worked with both ways, and feel that it's cleaner to just remove the UserControl type from the root all together if you are not utilizing UserControl specific properties.

Comment: Yeah, if that's your thing.